# live camera feed in background of Phonegap android app

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, camera

I want to make a phonegap android app which displays the live camera feed as the activity background. am a fairly experienced phonegap developer but am a total novice when it comes to mainstream android app development .

I found a native android solution:
[How to use camera live feed as a activity background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614715/android-use-camera-live-feed-as-a-activity-background)

But i really don't know how to intergrate it into my phonegap project.

does anybody have an idea how to go about this .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap : Camera view with background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268669/phonegap-camera-view-with-background-image)